# React Leaflet - Draw Bezier curve

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, drawing, bezier, react-leaflet

I have some difficulties to find a plugin for drawing Bezier curves on react leaflet map.

For drawing shapes, we are using an npm package react-leaflet-draw, but in this plugin, there is no option for drawing bezier curve.

How this can be done?
Is there is any plugin for this kind of a featchure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To draw a Bezier spline `@turf/bezier-spline` package (part of the [Turfjs project](http://turfjs.org/)) could be utilized which:

> Takes a line and returns a curved version by applying a [Bezier spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_spline)
>   algorithm

Here is an instruction how to integrate it with `React-Leaflet`:

- install the module: `$ npm install @turf/bezier-spline`
- calculate Bézier curve points via `bezierSpline` function and draw it via `GeoJSON` component

**Example**

```
const MapExample = props => {

  const line = helpers.lineString([
    [52.5069704,13.2846501],
    [47.3775499,8.4666755],
    [51.5287718,-0.2416804],
  ].map(latLng => [latLng[1],latLng[0]]));

  const curved = bezierSpline(line);

  return (
    <Map center={props.center} zoom={props.zoom}>
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
      <GeoJSON
        data={curved}
      />
    </Map>
  );
};
```

Here is [a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/5yq5yz0vml)

Comment: I have followed this approach and was able to get precise curves between two points. I'm wondering if there is a way to add a direction marker on curve. Kind of arrow, which indicates to and from?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/61915968/7498622

Comment: @StangSpree, would recommend  `Leaflet.PolylineDecorator` plugn for that matter