# Position a marker direction in react-leaflet facing a [long, lat]

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm trying to add a marker on GeoJSON bezier curve which connects origin and destination points. The marker needs to be positioned facing destination.

Here is the marker code:

```
<Marker position={midPoint} key={origin}>
  <Tooltip permanent direction="center" sticky>
    <span>
      &gt;
    </span>
  </Tooltip>
</Marker>
```

It would add markers at desired position

But those little ">" would not point towards destination.

Any solution for the above scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to consider is utilize [`Leaflet.PolylineDecorator` leaflet plug-in](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineDecorator) which supports drawing *arrow heads* among another features.

Here is an example how to utilize it along with `react-leaflet` library to draw *arrow heads*:

```
function DirectionsRoute(props) {
    const ctx = useLeaflet()
    const {coords} = props; 
    const {map} = ctx;


    function handleEachFeature(feature, layer){
        L.polylineDecorator(layer, {
          patterns: [
            {offset: '10%', repeat: '20%',  symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({pixelSize: 15, pathOptions: {fillOpacity: 1, weight: 0}})}
          ]
        }).addTo(map); 
    }


    return <GeoJSON data={coords} onEachFeature={handleEachFeature} />;
}
```

> Note:
>
> `offset` , `endOffset` and `repeat` options are used to control
>   pattern

Here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tkmmrg)

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Works perfect. I appreciate your response. I have applied couple of your other solutions as well to my app. Thanks so much!