# How to draw curve line in React.js

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to draw a curve line. I want o make a path. Is it possible to draw like a path in React.js?

[image: Path]

Comment: hi, I saw [this answer online](https://www.appsloveworld.com/reactjs/200/111/react-leaflet-draw-bezier-curve) that was apparently sourced from stackoverflow, but doesn't link to the original question/answer.. hopefully it will help you.   [Here's the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53522884/1675954)